# PAPERCLIP: How to list only users who have a image attached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I have the "paperclip" working in my app.

So, I want to list only chefs who have a image attached.

- ruby 1.9.2p290
- rails 3.1.1

In **HomeController**

> @chefs = Chef.where({:status_id => [0,1]}).all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10)

**In Home Index view**

```
<% @chefs.each do |chef| %>
  <%= image_tag chef.avatar.url(:thumb), :height => '50', :width => '50' %>
<% end %>
```

Is there way to put this condition in @chefs var?

If don't... how can I do this? I'm new in ruby/rails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this in HomeController:

```
@chefs = Chef.where({:status_id => [0,1]}).where('avatar_file_name is not null').all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10)
```

That will select only chefs whose status id is 0 or 1 and whose avatar file name is not null.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new in ruby/rails.